# Angular FireStore: applying snapshotChanges() on collection fetches all documents in collection, consume all read operation allowed quickly

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

One of my collection in Firebase's Cloud Firestore has 1500+ records. I am showing that data in a grid in my angular application. The problem is that whenever i refresh the page or as i am developing the application, so on each change/save action, it recompiles and reloads the page, which make 1500 documents read operation. I was assuming that firebase will cache the resultset automatically and snapshotChanges() will just return me the new/updated record but here i am not seeing any cache mechanism. Below is my code i am using to fetch data from Firebase.

```
getAllProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {

    return this.firestore.collection('Products').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {

      return actions.map(x => {
        const obj: any = x.payload.doc.data();
        obj.id = x.payload.doc.id;
        return obj as Product;
      });

    }));
  }
```

I think this is the very common usecase, but most probably i am missing something. Please suggest how can i reduce the number of read operation while maintaining an observable to my collection in CloudFirestore ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I was assuming that firebase will cache the resultset automatically and snapshotChanges() will just return me the new/updated record

The persistence layer provided by the Firestore SDK doesn't work like that.

The cache is primarily used to [support queries while offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline).  If you want to specifically use the cache instead of querying the server again, you will need to provide a [source option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options) with your query.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. but can you please suggest how can i reduce the number of read operations being made to firebase.. i am using free account and that allows only 50,000 read operations in a day, but since on one grid i have 1500 records so reloading that few times consumes all available limit. I can keep local copy of all these records in some service or browser-storage but then how can i get any updates being made to any of the document in that collection ?

Comment: What you're asking now is way too broad for discussion on a Stack Overflow comment.  Perhaps you want to post to a discussion group such as Reddit.