# take(1) on snapshotChanges() : is angular firestore get data from the server on second call even if data didn't change?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

I'm using Angular Firestore to access a Cloud Firestore database and on almost all my get requests I apply rxjs take(1) operator on snapshotChanges() to not listening to data changes after request is complete.

For instance :

```
export class myCollectionService {
   constructor(private db: AngularFirestore){}

   getData(){
      return this.db.collection<myCollection>("myCollection")
         .snapshotChanges()
         .pipe(take(1));
   }
}
```

What happens when I call getData() a second time? Is data gotten from the server even if nothing changes since the previous call or is there some caching mechanism?

Comment: As a sidenote, `.get()` is now supported by @angular/fire

Comment: Interesting, is get() has a kind of client caching or it just calls the server each time?

Comment: Both the functions (actually, all) do client caching. The first response is generally from client cache if available. You can check if your data is from cache or network request by `snapshot.metadata.fromCache`. More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: Caching seems enabled only when network is off. I was more thinking of something to avoid useless requests if content didn't change since previous request (like Etag implementation for example).

Comment: You cannot know if the content has changed or not without requesting it. And btw, firebase handles the network request intelligently if the cache is same as that on server. This is after a chat I had with a firebaser (firebase virtual meetup). I cannot say if you are charged for it.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as Community Wiki as it based partially in the comments.

Enabling access to data offline - as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) - would indeed be a very good idea for you, as you would be dealing with your cached data and you can configure when do you want it to upload with data from the server. Specifically for Angularfire with Firestore you can get more information [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-cloud-firestore-angularfire) - different way of doing, instead of `take(1)`.

Besides that, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63271753/12767257), the Firestore SDK doesn't cache automatically, so you need specifically to set that - for example, using the methods informed above. You can also confirm that by using `snapshot.metadata.fromCache` and verify if it's caching or not.

Comment: My primary concern is not really to manage an offline mode, it's more about avoiding useless requests to the server, so it seems I need to implement a caching strategy on my client app. 

If I understand well my only option is to make a cache with duration like "invalidate cache each 30s" whereas I was more hoping for a solution similar to Etag and invalidation based on content.

Comment: You can take a look a at this article [here](https://blog.angular.io/improved-querying-and-offline-data-with-angularfirestore-dab8e20a4a06) and verify if the `valueChanges()` function works for your goal of getting updated data when there is a change in the database. However, in case it doesn't, indeed, you will need to use a behavior related to the time of validity of the cache.

Comment: ValueChanges() and SnapshotChanges() doesn't really fit my needs as it automatically update data once there is a change. My page is displaying a posts list so it means each time a user will add or update an element, all clients will have the posts list updated whereas I just want the list to be updated on page navigation or user action. I would like to implement something similar to [HTTP Caching](https://www.logicbig.com/quick-info/web/etag-header.html) : Request with Etag header => if server Etag value is the same as the one in the request => 304 response and browser uses cached value.

Comment: Sure, I understand. Unfortunately, this type of caching wouldn't be possible to achieve. I would indeed recommend you to give it a try using the option available in Firestore.

Comment: I think I will have a look at REST API, it probably offers more flexibility regarding cache.